# how does accelerating charge produce Electromagnetic radiation?

Tags: electromagnetism

Suppose an electron is accelerating along $x-$axis. How does it produce electromagnetic radiation?

Which of Maxwell's equation comes in play and how do I derive the wave equation from it?

For oscillating charge the emerging EM wave is explained in [this video](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-02-electricity-and-magnetism-spring-2002/video-lectures/lecture-30-polarizers-and-maluss-law/). What kind of EM wave emerge out in this case (not oscillating but only accelerating in one direction)?
[image]

Comment: Hi there testuser. What does _"in which direction does it travel with respect to it's direction of travel"_ mean? And would you like to be specific about one single question - I think you've got several questions all bundled into one there.

Comment: In case of Oscillating charge, it is easy to visualize the electromagnetic radiation emerging radiation. If the charge is not oscillating but accelerating how does what kind of electromagnetic radiation emerges?

Comment: Also I decided to put different Questions for the latter part.

Comment: You still have *"in which direction does it travel with respect to it's direction of travel"*, which is horribly unclear because you have two "it"s the antecedents of which are ill-defined.

Comment: @dmckee i just want to know what kind of wave emerges out of it ... like in case of oscillating charge, it's easy to visualize like in [this video](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-02-electricity-and-magnetism-spring-2002/video-lectures/lecture-30-polarizers-and-maluss-law/)

Comment: In any case what part of this don't you understand? The field configuration depends on the charge configuration which you have defined as accelerating so there is a $\frac{d^2E}{dt^2}$. Is the problem conceptual or with bashing through the math? Finally, would you be satisfied with a more complicated charge configuration if it developed a simpler field configuration (the usual first example is the sinusoidal dipole, after all).

Comment: does Electric Field has to accelerate for electron to accelerate? can't constant electric field accelerate electron?

Comment: @testuser, have you perused [this](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath528/kmath528.htm)?