# How EM waves are produced by accelerating charged particles?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

1. How the electro-magnetic waves are produced by the accelerating charged particle? Graphical explanations are most welcomed.
2. Is the explanation given by the below mentioned article correct regarding the movement of electromagnetic waves?
   http://www.arrl.org/files/file/Technology/tis/Why%20an%20Antenna%20Radiates.pdf

Comment: I briefly closed this as a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34561/, but it seem that the earlier question is not very well defined as was closed. That said, this question currently has two distinct questions which goes against the functional model of Stack Exchange. Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: check out this question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46910/

Comment: @ArtBrown: And, that's the question of the *same author* :-)

Comment: @CrazyBuddy:  oops, should'a noticed that.  thanks.

Comment: @dmckee :Can I repost the 2nd question as a new thread?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Graphical explanations are most welcomed.

This is my personal favorite one of those (from MTW's "Gravitation").

[image]

For an animation, see, for example [this](http://www.cco.caltech.edu/~phys1/java/phys1/MovingCharge/MovingCharge.html) Java applet.

Answer (score 0):

For another excellent, and non-mathematical explanation on the cause of radiation see this EDN article: [Understanding electromagnetic fields and antenna radiation takes (almost) no math](https://www.edn.com/understanding-electromagnetic-fields-and-antenna-radiation-takes-almost-no-math/)

It breaks down different concepts rather nicely with plenty of graphics. It is, in fact, referenced from the Bible itself (not the holy one, but the one called *Art of Electronics* by Horowitz ...which itself is certainly sacred :D )

The article can also be downloaded as a PDF.