# Electromagnetic field of a point charge moving with constant velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics

Starting with this generalized formula for a electric field created by a point charge: $$\vec{E} =\frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \frac{r}{\left(\vec{r}\cdot\vec{u}\right)^3} [(c^2 − v^2)\vec{u} + \vec{r} × (\vec{u} × \vec{a})] \tag1$$

I was able to show that the electric field of point charge $q$ is constrained to move along the $x$ axis with velocity $v$ is:

$$\vec{E} = \frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \frac{1}{r^2} \left(\frac{c + v}{c - v}\right)\tag2$$

However, according to what I deducted from "Introduction to Electrodynamics" by David J. Griffiths, when a point charge $q$ moves along $x$ axis with velocity $v$, without being constrained the electric field is:

$$\vec{E} = \frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \frac{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}{\left(1-\frac{v^2 \sin^2\left (\theta \right)}{c^2}\right)^{3/2}} \frac{\hat{R}}{R^2}\tag3$$

$\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{R}$, if $\theta = 0$, wouldn't it be the case where a point charge is contrained? If so, wouldn't give the exact same electric field?

When I plug $\theta = 0$, I get $$\vec{E} = \frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \frac{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}{R^2}\hat{R}\tag4,$$
which clearly isn't the same as (2).

Is my reasoning wrong or is it supposed to be different?

Comment: Related : [Electric field associated with moving charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/296904/electric-field-associated-with-moving-charge/426795#426795).

Comment: $\theta=0$ just means that you are only looking at the field along the direction of the velocity. It doesn't determine the direction the particle is moving.

Comment: $\mathbf{R}$ is the position vector of the field point with respect to the *present* position, while $\mathbf{r}$ is the position vector of the field point with respect to the *retarded* position. Your equation (2) yields the electric field on **a point on the**  $x-$ **axis to the right of the charge**  $q$. To derive equation (2) from equation (4) you must find how  $R$ and  $r$  are related for a field point on the $x-$axis to the right of the charge $q$. See also **Problem 10.18** in the 3rd edition of *'Introduction to Electrodynamics'* by David J. Griffiths.

Comment: @Frobenius Ahhh! I understand it know, thank you very much!