# Magnetic Field Production

Tags: electromagnetism

Why does a moving point charge does not produce a magnetic field? why does it always have to be a current? I am a high-school student with knowledge of basic calculus.

Comment: Related :  [Electric field associated with moving charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/296904/electric-field-associated-with-moving-charge/426795#426795).

Answer (score 3):

A moving point charge does produce a magnetic field (along with an electric field). After all a current is essentially a collection of moving point charges.

The magnetic field of a point charge moving with a constant velocity $\vec v$ can be approximately [determined from Biot-Savart's law or more accurately by Maxwell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot%E2%80%93Savart_law#Point_charge_at_constant_velocity). In vaccum it is given by: $$\vec B = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}.\frac {q \vec v \text{ x }  \hat r}{r^2}$$ provided $v \ll c$ ; the speed of light

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not strictly correct. Biot-Savart applies to steady-state currents and a single charge is not that.

Comment: @IcyOtter, Biot-Savart's law applies to current _elements_ and these can easily be modified to a single charge by substituing $$I = n_v .q.A.v$$ (from Drude's model of electrical conduction) with $n_v A.ds = 1$ to give the desired result.

Comment: That's not what your post says. You are saying that the B field from a point charge in vacuum is given by the expression you provided. That is not correct. A B-field of a point charge cannot be obtained from B-S law. It must include retardation effects: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liénard–Wiechert_potential . In the limit v << c, B-S is a decent approximation.

Comment: You're right about the approximation. I've edited my answer.

Comment: upvoted the answer:)