# High speed electron and magnetic field

Tags: magnetic-fields, electrons, acceleration, velocity

We know that when an electron moves at a velocity,it produces magnetic field.

My question is how strong the magnetic field will be if electron moves at a velocity $v$ or with an acceleration $a$ and by what formula.

Comment: For the vectors $\,\mathbf E,\,\mathbf B\,$ of the electromagnetic field produced by an arbitrary moving point charge see equations (01.1),(01.2) in my amswer here : [Electric field associated with moving charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/296904/electric-field-associated-with-moving-charge), equations (14.14),(14.13) extracted from J.D.Jackson's *$^{\prime}$Classical Electrodynamics$^{\prime}$*, 3rd Edition.

Comment: For the vectors $\,\mathbf E,\,\mathbf B\,$ of the electromagnetic field produced by an uniformly moving point charge see the relativistic equations (01a),(01b) in my amswer here : [Magnetic field due to a single moving charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/412924/magnetic-field-due-to-a-single-moving-charge), equations produced by Lienard-Wiechert potentials. In this same answer for the vector $\,\mathbf B\,$ from  a slowly moving point charge see the non-relativistic equation (02) produced by the Biot-Savart Law.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this equation to find the field produced by a moving charge (or an electron in this specific case) with this equation:-

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{B}\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{\mu_{0}}{4\pi}\dfrac{q\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{\hat{r}}\right)}{r^2}
\end{equation}
And In the case in which the velocity is time dependent then you will have to substitute the term $v$ with the function of time and you will get the variable magnetic field strength with the variable velocity.

I suggest you to please have a look at [this](https://cnx.org/contents/atl-mE0g@1/The-Biot-Savart-Law-for-point-charges-and-wires) article.

Comment: why mass $m$ is used in the formula? What will be the SI unit of that formula?

Comment: @KaushikKumbhat that is not only $m$, I've written  $mu$ "mu" is a Greek letter, and here it's used to denote the term know as permeability of air or vacuum, that symbol was not available in my keyboard so I was unable to put the actual symbol. But I'll rectify this issue soon!

Comment: Okay that's done you can go through the answer now!

Comment: @Frobenius I'm curious to know about what your edit mean!

Comment: You're right. I don't realize, because of the small size font,  that you have the unit vector $\mathbf{\hat{r}}$ and not $\mathbf r$. So, I edit your equation to be more clear. If you don't agree I'll turn it as you post it initially..

Comment: @Frobenius No it's completely fine now and looks good than before, thank you brother/sister it actually helped me to understand how to write the answers properly. My mistake that I've written it too small! I apologize for these issues.

Comment: Don't worry. No matter...and... Welcome to PSE.

Comment: Tejas, a note on symbols : for vectors we usually  have either boldface symbols like $\mathbf a$,  $\boldsymbol \omega$ or regular symbols with an arrow like $\vec{a}$, $\vec{\omega}$ but almost never both of them like  $\vec{\mathbf a}$,  $\vec{\boldsymbol \omega}$.

Comment: @Frobenius Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133451/discussion-between-tejas-dahake-and-frobenius).