# Why does the area close to a charged particle move at the exact speed as the particle itself?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation

when a charged particle moves the area around it moves at the same speed as the particle itself so if the particle had a velocity of 10m/s down then the electric waves at a 10m radius around it moves that the exact speed according to khan academy, but shouldn't they move at a slightly different velocity since there is another velocity down?

photo for clarity [image: this is a picture of what I mean but in a different direction]

Comment: You seem to be assuming that particles have a spatial extent, but in 1915's General Relativity, they've been treated as "point-like", and, consequently, lack any.  There's a 1929 version of Einsteinian relativity, worked out thru conversations between Einstein and the mathematician Cartan, known as Einstein-Cartan-Sciama-Kibble Theory (after more recent modifications by Sciama & Kibble), that assigns a tiny spatial extent to fermions, but the only application of it I've seen has been in a cosmological model by Nikodem Poplawski, found by his name on <<Arxiv>>.

Comment: *there is another velocity down* What do you mean by that?

Comment: Related : [Electric field associated with moving charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/296904/electric-field-associated-with-moving-charge).

Comment: @Edouard I think the question is about the field near a moving *point* charge.

Comment: @Ghoster --Yes, I think you're right, given the tags, the graphic, the other comments, and the lack of edits.  I hope my ineptitude did not contribute unduly to the closure of what I believe had been a "first question" when I saw it.