# Why are not kinks produced for constant speed charge?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electromagnetic-radiation

Why arent kinks produced when the charge moves at constant velocity in the same linear direction ?

I am asking this because this is the backbone of why EM wave is not created for constant velocity charge.

Seems like even if charge moves at constant speed,, the new location definately has a new electric field lines(slighty different directions than the previous location’s field vectors). So this still should cause the kinks produced. (Kink is the joined vector between the old and new vector lines due to electric fields cant break)

Could not find an animation of electric field vectors while charge is in a constant speed motion.

What I mean by kink is the following source: [Link](https://youtu.be/1OUW4nbrZgc) . The kink is shown at 05:07

Comment: "Constant speed" and "at each movement" doesn't make sense, especially if you mean constant _velocity_.  A constant velocity particle doesn't _have_ separate motions -- it just goes.  Please _edit your question_ to clarify what you mean by "at each movement", and whether you mean a constant-speed but curved path, or a true constant velocity path.

Comment: and while you are editing your question per @TimWescott, please define what a kink is, I am not familiar with that electromagnetic concept.

Comment: @hyportnex The OP means [this kink](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/296904/electric-field-associated-with-moving-charge). See the comments on the OP’s [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/766025/why-does-the-kink-has-the-following-vector-direction), and the answer.