# Relativistic electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, spacetime, charge, time-dilation

Assuming a charged particle moves at speeds near the speed of the light.  Will the electric field generated by that particle get affected by length contraction and time dilation?
In other words, will this cause a more dense field closer to the particle which declines faster with distance compared to a stationary charged particle?

Comment: Yes. The field gets stronger out to the side, and weaker front and back. No doubt someone will answer more fully.

Comment: Related : [Electric field associated with moving charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/296904/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electric field associated with moving charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/296904/)

Comment: https://galileoandeinstein.phys.virginia.edu/Elec_Mag/2022_Lectures/EM_64_figs/image003.png

Comment: For a point charge in uniform motion, the electric field is still radial, and the field strength still decreases as the inverse square of the distance, but the field strength now depends on the angle from the direction of motion; it is no longer isotropic. [Derivation](https://galileoandeinstein.phys.virginia.edu/Elec_Mag/2022_Lectures/EM_64_SR_Electromagnetism.html)