# Acceleration of uncharged particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics

Following on from [this comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/186361/why-does-moving-electron-emits-photons?noredirect=1#comment393959_186361) - *do* uncharged particles radiate under acceleration? (no offense to the commenter, just clarifying as I've not heard of this before)

Why is this? I vaguely recall a satisfying explanation (will link if I find it) for charged particles that rested on them having charge, so am a bit lost imagining how this works for uncharged particles.

Broader question: does this mean that anything that accelerates, necessarily radiates something else?

Comment: I believe leptons would radiate Ws and Zs, but truthfully, I don't think one can actually separate the electroweak force in the standard model like that.

Comment: what kind of acceleration... "g?" and is this [Larmor formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula) applicable in this case?

Comment: Please read my answer http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/186361/

Comment: https://indico.cern.ch/event/153576/material/slides/1?contribId=45 (Coherent Bremsstrahlung from Fast Neutrons)

Comment: @HolgerFiedler Thanks, I had a look at your answer already but wasn't sure how it applies to uncharged; I'll have a look at the article and come back to this.

Comment: Ok, so if I'm understanding it correctly, it's _still_ the same effect as for charged particles, but the issue is that some particles considered uncharged like neutron actually have non-zero electric dipole and magnetic moments that permit them to interact (albeit weakly, however, necessarily) with photons?

Comment: Xeren Narcy, neutrons don't have electric charge but have magnetic dipole moment and intrinsic spin.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler I'm not suggesting neutrons have electric charge, but that they may (or do) have non-zero electric dipole moment. I would think a spinning electric dipole would generate a magnetic moment...

Comment: Magnetic dipol moment is a intrinsic property and it is related to the intrinsic spin only.