# How do traveling far field radio waves break free from the non-traveling near field conditions at the transmitter antenna?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

I would like to know how far field traveling electromagnetic radio waves separate from the near field non-traveling electromagnetic fields at a radio transmitter antenna.  How is a non-traveling electromagnetic field converted into a traveling electromagnetic field?

Comment: Even the near field has "travelling" components as you put it.

Comment: Yes, but they only travel to very restricted locations near the source antenna.

Comment: I'm having a hard time getting a decent answer to this simple question from the usual sources on the internet.  Perhaps physics has no good answer at the present time.  That's why I have asked the question on this physics forum.

Comment: or perhaps it is the wrong question. (well that's what always happens to me).  Is they answer they separate because they don;t interact anyway and because they travel away from each other? If not why not.

Answer (score 2):

You are confused. The near-field and far-field components are *both* present at all distances from the antenna. The difference is that whilst the near-field component(s) fall of in amplitude as $\sim r^{-2}$, the far-field components fall off as $r^{-1}$. In other words, they co-exist, but one can define three regions: one where the near-field dominates (at small $r$), one where the far-field dominates (at large $r$) and a third where they are of comparable magnitude and must both be considered.

There is no black & white dividing line between these regions - it depends on the purpose of your calculations/investigations. Typically one says that the far-field radiation field dominates if $r \gg \lambda/2\pi$ (where $\lambda$ is the wavelength of the far-field radiation) and if $r \gg l$, where $l$ is the dimension of the antenna. What $\gg$ means is entirely a matter for you.

Comment: Why does the amplitude of the near field fall off as r-2, while that of the far field falls off at r-1 ?

Comment: Because that is the definition of the "near field". If it fell of as $r^{-1}$ then it wouldn't be the near field @JohnPetrovic If you are asking why there is a near field and a far field, well think about the field of an accelerating charge - there will obviously be some static "Coulomb component" that varies as $r^{-2}$.

Comment: Think about this.  A single moving electron generates a magnetic field around it that moves (i.e. changes in space) with the motion of the electron.  Many moving electrons in an antenna produce a magnetic field in the vicinity of the antenna.  How does this lead to the formation of an independently traveling electromagnetic radio wave that no longer interacts with the moving electrons in the antenna?  This is what I am trying to understand.

Comment: Because a "moving" electron doesn't generate EM waves, only an accelerating electron does that. And if you are talking about a linear antenna then of course the far-field component is zero along the direction of the antenna.

Comment: Tell me how an accelerating electron produces an electromagnetic wave, that's what I want to understand.

Comment: That was not your question, which would have been a duplicate of  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46946/how-em-waves-are-produced-by-accelerating-charged-particles?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

I read a bit t[he wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_and_far_field) on near and far field and antennas.

To start with **an electromagnetic wave always travels with velocity c** , no matter how the interference patterns of continuous emissions appear.

An analogy: When one is near a lamp one can see the emitting wires or diodes, which means that it is not a plane wave of light but it has a particular structure , at a distance the light source follows the 1/r^2 law of dispersion from a point source and can be described by a spherical wave.

> I would like to know how far field traveling electromagnetic radio waves separate from the near field non-traveling electromagnetic fields at a radio transmitter antenna .

It is not a matter of separating electromagnetic waves, but of diminishing importance of the interference patterns that control the near fields due to the small distance from the source  and the shape of the source, the wavelength being the gauge.

[image: nearfarfield]

What you call "non traveling " wave is a misnomer. It is a non traveling diffraction pattern. Diffraction patterns are dependent on the continuous emission of the electromagnetic wave from the particular topology of the antenna. At a distance, as the beam opens in angle and the energy density drops these diffraction patterns disappear and a dipole pattern of energy density  dominates , if the antenna is a dipole.

Comment: This diagram is from Wikipedia near and far field waves.  But it does not answer my question.  My question is what happens at the line in the diagram that separates fresnel radiative waves from far field waves.

Comment: The diagram is for people who are not clear for far field and near field meanings. My answer states  that there is NO line, rather the line is a few wavelengths wide, of continuously fading interference. The near field interferences fade away in a few wavelengths due to the opening rays  and only the radial 1/r^2 behavior remains. Do not confuse interference patterns of em waves with the em waves.

Comment: Interference effects happen when multiple wave patterns interact with each other.  Since one radio wave is generated by each cycle of the charges moving in the antenna, where do these additional wave patterns come from?

Comment: In electromagnetism the  waves do not interact. They overlap, it is in the quantum mechanical regime, the wavefunctions are superposed, and their comlex conjugate squared show the interference patterns in the energy content of the beam. The classical wave also, but it is not an interaction, it is an overlap because by their construction the waves are in phase .

Answer (score 0):

A perfect oscillator may create electric field in a capacitor, and magnetic
field in an inductor, and (being 'perfect') will not radiate.   That's not useful for a radio, so we add a component, the antenna, that has both electric and magnetic fields, but which ALSO has a loss element, a resistive component
to its impedance.

The energy loss in an antenna is intended to be radiation out into space of
an electromagnetic wave.   The OTHER parts of the energy provided to
the antenna are NOT lost, they just cycle energy from inductor/magnetic field energy
to capacitive/electric field energy, back and forth, just like an inductor and capacitor (LC tank circuit).

To evaluate an antenna design, the how-much-power-is-emitted question requires a
calculation of the fields near the antenna, due to the supplied current at the
transmitter frequency.   That is important, because nearby objects (the transmitter tower, the ground) and the shape of the antenna elements, determines beam direction.  The radiated intensity, though, in any given direction, will
only depend on the way those local fields couple to a wave-equation traveling
wave solution.   So, after solving local fields, one also finds a second part
solution, to the far field traveling wave that delivers radio to your receiver.

The calculation has two parts.   The physical situation is only ONE part,
but we can use approximations at a distance that wouldn't work up close
to the antenna (where we care about different answers, anyhow).